# How to distinguish M[2, ] from M[2]?

Tags: r, r-s4

I defined some S4 matrices, whose class is `lazyMatrix`. If `M` is such a matrix, I want to define `M[2, ]` as the second row of `M`, and `M[2]` as the second coefficient of `M` (when enumerating the coefficients column after column).

So I defined these two S4 methods:

```r
setMethod( # to extract a coefficient
  "[", 
  signature("lazyMatrix", i = "numeric"), 
  function(x, i) {
    ......
  }
)

setMethod( # to extract a row
  "[", 
  signature("lazyMatrix", i = "numeric", j = "missing", drop = "ANY"), 
  function(x, i, j, drop) {
    ......
  }
)
```

But both `M[2, ]` and `M[2]` return the second row of `M`. I tried to exchange the order of the two method definitions, that does not change anything.

Answer (score 6):

I found a solution in the source code of the **onion** package:

```r
setMethod(
  "[", 
  signature("lazyMatrix", i = "numeric", j = "missing", drop = "missing"), 
  function(x, i, j, ..., drop) {
    n_args <- nargs()
    if(n_args == 3L) { # M[i, ]
      ......  
    } else if(n_args == 2L) { # M[i]
      ......
    } else {
      stop("Invalid arguments in subsetting.")
    }
  }
)

setMethod(
  "[", 
  signature("lazyMatrix", i = "numeric", j = "missing", drop = "ANY"), 
  function(x, i, j, ..., drop) {
    n_args <- nargs()
    if(n_args == 4L) { # M[i, ]
      ......  
    } else if(n_args == 3L) { # M[i]
      ......
    } else {
      stop("Invalid arguments in subsetting.")
    }
  }
)
```

Before finding this solution, I tried using `nargs()` in my attempts, unsuccessfully. The trick is to add the `...` argument. But I don't understand how this works. Please leave another answer or a comment if you can explain.

Answer (score 2):

The dispatch issue has nothing to do with the dots, though it *is* problematic that the formal arguments of your methods do not match those of the generic function:

```r
> getGeneric("[")
```

```
standardGeneric for "[" defined from package "base"

function (x, i, j, ..., drop = TRUE) 
standardGeneric("[", .Primitive("["))
<bytecode: 0x1403d1a28>
<environment: 0x1403c9d10>
Methods may be defined for arguments: x, i, j, drop
Use  showMethods([)  for currently available ones.
```

`?setMethod` is quite clear about that:

> The definition must be a function with the same formal arguments as the generic; however, `setMethod()` will handle methods that add arguments, if `...` is a formal argument to the generic.  See the Details section.

Anyway, the real issue is that `setMethod` interprets your first signature

```r
signature("lazyMatrix", i = "numeric")
```

as

```r
signature("lazyMatrix", i = "numeric", j = "ANY", drop = "ANY")
```

and both of the calls `M[2]` and `M[2, ]` match your second signature

```r
signature("lazyMatrix", i = "numeric", j = "missing", drop = "ANY")
```

more closely than the first (because `"missing"` is more specific than `"ANY"`).  Hence dispatch in both cases favours the second method.

It is still true that the primitive function `[` is the trickiest generic function out there, due to all of the special cases handled in C code for traditional matrices (of implicit class `matrix`).  The `nargs()` approach is correct and also used by package `Matrix`, which is really the canonical reference for this kind of thing:

```r
> library(Matrix)
> selectMethod("[", signature = c("Matrix", "numeric", "missing", "missing"))
```

```
Method Definition:

function (x, i, j, ..., drop = TRUE) 
{
    Matrix.msg("M[i,m,m] : nargs()=", nargs(), .M.level = 2)
    if (nargs() == 2) {
        .M.vectorSub(x, i)
    }
    else {
        callGeneric(x, i = i, , drop = TRUE)
    }
}
<bytecode: 0x128e94a90>
<environment: namespace:Matrix>

Signatures:
        x        i         j         drop     
target  "Matrix" "numeric" "missing" "missing"
defined "Matrix" "index"   "missing" "missing"
```